# the for loop within a list?

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

I'm still a beginner at learning Python. I want to ask something about loops. I found a written code like this:

```
user_ids = [u for u, c in user_ids_count.most_common(n)]
movie_ids = [m for m, c in movie_ids_count.most_common(m)]
```

how to read this code? I know that `user_ids` is the object and `user_ids_count.most_common()` is the function/method (please correct me if I'm wrong), but I have no idea what the logic sense of `u for u, c` and what does that mean because I can't find any loops example that's written like this.

Comment: This is a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: The generator(s) of a comprehension share the same keywords (`for` and `in`) with a `for` loop, but they are distinct syntactic constructs.

Comment: I am out of close votes for today, but the canonical duplicate is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/).

Comment: Thank you for the references. I just know about a list comprehension because I didn't learn it in my basic course and didn't stumble on it while searching on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The `user_ids_count.most_common()` is the function/method. But the `user_ids` is a variable that stores the address for a list that you are creating.

The `user_ids_count.most_common()` method returns a list of tuples which means each element in that list consists of two values. With `u for u, c in`, you make an iteration on the list elements, in each iteration assign the first value in the tuple to `u`, and the second value in the tuple to `c`. Then you build a new array with `u` values.

Here is an example:

```
[u for u, c in [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]]
```

will return:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```